# AspnetCore SpaServices Error as when I type dotnet run it always gives me this error

Tags: angular, asp-net-core-spa-services

I  I have already Installed AspNetCore SDK and nodejs npm but there is an error that i want answer to it

```
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npmfail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! errno 1

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! Vega@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "53901"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Vega@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.


 npmfail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Can you run `npm start` inside your *ClientApp* folder and tell us the output ?

Comment: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Comment: Delete your node_modules folder and reinstall it : `npm i` then try again